How do packages like Tensorflow or PyTorch distribute their shared libraries
Just some background, I am creating a package that ties into some C++ and wanted to know how some other larger codebases handle this. I know that many popular Python libraries like the above-mentioned ones are written mostly in C++ (and use a shared library like libtensorflow.so for example). I was just wondering how specifically they distribute the shared library. Do they have a a set of them embedded in the package i.e. .dylib, .so, .dll for MacOS, Linux, and Windows respectively? My initial thought was that these packages exported the shared library file for each platform/architecture in some distribution folder but I couldn't find anything like that. Any help or expertise is appreciated, thanks.

Usually, dynamic link libraries are distributed along with packages. Take Pytorch for example, when installing pytorch==2.2.1+cu121, linux users download the package from:
https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu121/torch-2.2.1%2Bcu121-cp312-cp312-linux_x86_64.whl

while the Windows users download from:
https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu121/torch-2.2.1%2Bcu121-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl

It can be found that when downloading the same version of the same package, users using different systems and chip architectures will get different wheel files. The dynamic link library version in each wheel file corresponds to the platform of the wheel file name. (Actually, there are certain rules for the wheels, see PEP 427, PEP 491.)
You may have a deeper understanding of this by looking at the local torch directory. On Linux, there are _C.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so and a bunch of dynamic library files like lib/xxx.so. On Windows, the files are _C.cp312-win_amd64.pyd, lib/xxx.lib and lib/xxx.dll. When calling the dynamic link library, just import torch._C and the symbols can be accessed through this.
After building the dynamic link library, you need to manually add these files to the wheel. For example, if your compiled files are in the lib directory, you need to specify package_data in setup.py to include them in the wheel file. This is an example:
# setup.py
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

package_data = ['lib/*.so*', 'lib/*.dylib*', 'lib/*.dll', 'lib/*.lib']
setup(
    name='your package name',
    version='your package version',
    packages=find_packages(),
    package_data=package_data,
)

You can refer to pytorch/setup.py for a more detailed example for setup.py.
In summary, you can distribute your package in three steps:

Build your package on different platforms.
Rename the built wheels according to PEP conventions.
Upload the wheels to PyPI. (I'm not sure whether PyPI handles the platform issue automatically, though.)

If you need an example for how to distribute the wheels, you can see how pytorch does it at this link.

Understood, I guess my next question is how are the shared libraries added to the whl (I know each platform and architecture have their own .whl). Sorry I don’t see much documentation regarding this

What you need may be the package_data. See this document for more information.

They do provide a way to either build locally or a prebuilt package like below
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/c/README.md

Not enough "meat" in this answer to withstand the test of time and the rotting of links. You may be able to salvage this answer by summarizing the relevant contents of the link.

Got it, so when you install the package with pip install tensorflow it downloads from that URL?

@RonanMKelly No, pip downloads from preconfigured "indices". The default index is pypi.org so pip install tensorflow downloads from https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/#files
